# Create procedure and Insert values in Table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Create a procedure named `insert_credit` to insert the values in the `credit_card` table by passing 5 inputs as parameters.

Procedure name:    `insert_credit`

Input parameter : `credit_id with data type as number,credit_card_number with data type as varchar,credit_card_expire with data type as varchar,holder_name with data type as varchar and card_type with data type as varchar`

Table used: `credit_card`

I wrote this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_credit(
       p_credit_id IN credit_card.credit_id%TYPE,  
       p_credit_card_number IN credit_card.credit_card_number%TYPE,  
       p_credit_card_expire IN credit_card.credit_card_expire%TYPE,  
       p_holder_name IN credit_card.holder_name%TYPE,  
       p_card_type IN credit_card.card_type%TYPE)  
IS  
BEGIN  

   INSERT INTO credit_card ("credit_id", "credit_card_number",   "credit_card_expire", "holder_name","card_type")   
  VALUES (p_credit_id, p_credit_card_number,p_credit_card_expire,  
 p_holder_name,p_card_type);  

  COMMIT;  

END;  
/
```

On executing I am getting :

> " Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors."

Comment: You can see details on the error by running `show errors`. But try to get rid of the `"` around the column names unless you also used them when you created that table

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE insert_credit(
credit_id IN credit_card.id%TYPE,
credit_card_number IN credit_card.card_number%TYPE,
credit_card_expire IN credit_card.card_expire%TYPE,
holder_name IN credit_card.name%TYPE,
card_type IN credit_card.cc_type%TYPE) AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO credit_card(id,card_number,card_expire,name,cc_type)
VALUES(credit_id,credit_card_number,credit_card_expire,holder_name,card_type);
END insert_credit;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to debug your procedure you can run it like a anonymous block and all declare all input parameter.

```
/*CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_credit(
       p_credit_id IN credit_card.credit_id%TYPE,  
       p_credit_card_number IN credit_card.credit_card_number%TYPE,  
       p_credit_card_expire IN credit_card.credit_card_expire%TYPE,  
       p_holder_name IN credit_card.holder_name%TYPE,  
       p_card_type IN credit_card.card_type%TYPE)  
IS  */
declare
p_credit_id credit_card.credit_id%TYPE := somevalue
...
..
...
P_card_type

BEGIN  

   INSERT INTO credit_card ("credit_id", "credit_card_number",   "credit_card_expire", "holder_name","card_type")   
  VALUES (p_credit_id, p_credit_card_number,p_credit_card_expire,  
 p_holder_name,p_card_type);  

  COMMIT;  

END;
```

Now you will be able to get the line where you are getting error. After the block run without any error you can remove the declaration part and uncomment the commented code.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_credit(
credit_id NUMBER,
credit_card_number VARCHAR,
credit_card_expire VARCHAR,
holder_name VARCHAR,
card_type VARCHAR) 
AS
   /*Declaration block*/
   
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO credit_card(id,card_number,card_expire,name,cc_type)
  VALUES(credit_id,credit_card_number,credit_card_expire,holder_name,card_type);
  
END insert_credit;
/
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.